# How to Pass image from table cell to UIImage object in UIView using segue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, segue

I have a table view and UIView.Table view cell is having cells with image.I want when perticuler cell is selected the corresponding image should appear in "UIImage object" in UIView.

In table view class:

```
//I'm getting temp image as following(in my "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method)
  if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        [[cell imageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greekChickenSalad.png"]];
        tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greekChickenSalad.png"];
    }

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SubRecipeDescriptionSegue"])
{
     RecipeDescriptionViewController *rdVC;
    rdVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    rdVC.parentIndexRDVC = descriptionIndexPath;
    rdVC.DescriptionLabel = (UILabel*)subRecipeSelected;
    rdVC.image = tempImage;

}

}
```

In UIView, LoadView method adding image like following:

```
NSData *imageDataString = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageNamedContent = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[imageDataString bytes] length:[imageDataString length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamedContent];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(30,30, 250, 100);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

In above code, I'm converting image to NSString([UIImage imageNamed:imageNamedContent]) - Is this correct?

If not, How can I do this?

**Note: Segue is working fine if I'm passing table cell's text to a label in UIView.**

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: You are not converting an image to string. You are creating the new image using the file name which is a string.

Comment: This is the image to string conversion...NSData *imageDataString = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageNamedContent = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[imageDataString bytes] length:[imageDataString length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; My "image is a property".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
NSData *imageDataString = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageNamedContent = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[imageDataString bytes] length:[imageDataString length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamedContent];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];
```

Into:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
```

---

---

Also you need to get the image of the current cell and send it with the performSegueWithIdentifier:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubRecipeDescriptionSegue" sender:cell.imageView.image];
}
```

Then you need to update your prepareForSegue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SubRecipeDescriptionSegue"])
    {
        UIImage *selectedImage = (UIImage*)sender;

        RecipeDescriptionViewController *rdVC;
        rdVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        rdVC.parentIndexRDVC = descriptionIndexPath;
        rdVC.DescriptionLabel = (UILabel*)subRecipeSelected;
        rdVC.image = selectedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes,I'm doing that only.I have property like following in "RecipeDescriptionViewController":@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImage *image; And, in Segue sender(above code) i'm doing "rdVC.image = tempImage;"

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In this case, what ever cell I select, I'm getting image of the last cell.

Comment: Thanks.I was doing image selection in wrong method.Now I changed it to "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" And working fine.